# 撮影直後にオリジナル画像を取得したい

Tags: android, olympus-camerakit

Android用のOLYMPUSのSDK（CameraKit）を利用してての質問です。

撮影直後に、その撮影した写真のJPEGファイルを取得をしたいと考えてます。
現在提供されているAPIでは、「撮影結果確認用画像」は取得できるのですが、
撮影画像のオリジナル画像は取得出来ません。
上記「撮影結果確認用画像」のプロパティ「RECVIEW」のように、
「撮影後保存用のオリジナルサイズ画像」を取得できるような方法がありますか

Answer (score 4):

OPCサポートです。
質問ありがとうございます。

撮影直後に撮影画像取得するには以下の２つの方法が考えられます。

**方法１）　撮影画像の保存先設定を変更する**

カメラプロパティーDESTINATION_FILEをDESTINATION_FILE_WIFIに設定すると、撮影画像をモバイルデバイスへ直接転送できます。撮影画像はonReceiveCapturedImageで取得できます。このとき撮影画像はカメラ本体のmicroSDカードには保存されませんのでご注意ください。

制限事項は、以下のとおりです。

- 連写設定ができない。
- 動画撮影時には自動的にmicroSDカードに動画が保存される。

**方法２）　撮影前後のファイルリストの差分を検出し、差分ファイルのみ転送する**

撮影前と撮影後でmicroSDカード内のファイルリストを取得し、差分を検出して、差分ファイルのみ転送する方法があります。

- 撮影前にdownloadContentListで予めmicroSDカード内のファイルリストを取得しておきます。
- 撮影後、isMediaBusyがtrue→falseになったタイミングで再度downloadContentListを再度実行します。
- ファイルリストの差分を調べます。
- 差分のファイルをdownloadImage(IMAGE_RESIZE_NONE)で転送します。

downloadImageにて画像を転送する前にstopLiveView実行し、ライブビュー転送を停止すると転送時間を短縮できます。ライブビュー転送を再開するためには、画像転送完了後にstartLiveView実行してください。

Comment: "撮影画像の保存先設定を変更する"方法を試してみました。
　DESTINATION_FILEを<DESTINATION_FILE/DESTINATION_FILE_WIFI>にsetCameraPropertyValueして
　その後、getCameraPropertyValueにて<DESTINATION_FILE/DESTINATION_FILE_WIFI>に設定されていることを
　確認しました。

　撮影後、onReceiveCapturedImageではなく、onReceiveCapturedImagePreviewがコールバックされてしまいます。

　OPCのSDには撮影画像が保存されていないことからDESTINATION_FILEの設定はDESTINATION_FILE_WIFIに
　設定されていると思います。

　onReceiveCapturedImageとonReceiveCapturedImagePreviewの両方にブレークポイントを設定しているのですが、
　何故かonReceiveCapturedImagePreviewしか呼ばれません。

Comment: コードを示していただけますか？あるいはCamera Kitのサンプルコードをベースに開発されていますか？

Comment: Camera Kitのサンプルコードをベースで作成しております

Comment: 撮影サンプルアプリ(ImageCaptureSample)を修正していただいているということでよろしいでしょうか。詳細が不明ですが、一部推測で回答いたします。

LiveViewFragmentの`onReceiveCapturedImagePreview`内でRecviewFragmentに画面遷移していると思います。LiveViewFragmentは`onPause`で`camera.setRecordingSupportsListener(null)`としており、ここで`onReceiveCapturedImage`がコールバックされなくなります。

LiveViewFragmentの`onReceiveCapturedImagePreview`内の処理を削除し、RecviewFragmentへ画面遷移しないように変更すると`onReceiveCapturedImage`がコールバックされるのがご確認いただけると思います。

このときカメラプロパティー RECVIEWがONでも問題ないことを確認しております。
以上ご確認いただけますでしょうか。

Comment: 早速試してみました、無事に問題が解決致しました。ありがとうございます